# My B64 Encoder doesn't work

Tags: c, encoding, character-encoding, base64, decode

Hi I made a base 64 encoder and some of it works but not 100% and its driving me crazy why it won't work.

```
int b64_encode(FILE *in, FILE *out)
{
do
{
char outbuf [76+3];// room for null \n \r
char inbuf [57];//ratio 4ascii/3chars
for(int i=0; i < sizeof(inbuf);i++)
    inbuf[i]=0;
int i1;
int i2;
int i3;
int o1;
int o2;
int o3;
int o4;
int combine;
size_t read_cnt;
read_cnt = fread(inbuf,1,sizeof(inbuf),in);
for (int i = 0; i < read_cnt; i=i+3)
{
    i3 = inbuf[i+2];
    i2 =inbuf[i+1] << 8;
    i1 = inbuf[i] << 16;
    combine = i1+i2+i3;
    o4 = (combine & 0x3f);
    combine = combine >> 6;
    o3 = (combine & 0x3f);
    combine = combine >> 6;
    o2 = (combine & 0x3f);
    combine = combine >> 6;
    o1 = (combine & 0x3f);
    combine = combine >> 6;
    outbuf[i*4/3]=ENCODE[o1];
    outbuf[i*4/3+1]=ENCODE[o2];
    outbuf[i*4/3+2]=ENCODE[o3];
    outbuf[i*4/3+3]=ENCODE[o4];
}
for(int i=0; i < sizeof(outbuf);i++)
{
    if(outbuf[i]==0)
    {
        outbuf[i+2]='\0';
        outbuf[i]='\r';
        outbuf[i+1]='\n';
        i=sizeof(outbuf);
    }
}
//padding
if((read_cnt%3)==2)
{
    int t= (int)read_cnt;
    int temp= ((t/3)+1)*4;
    outbuf[temp-1] = '=';
}
if((read_cnt%3)==1)
{
    int t= (int)read_cnt;
    int temp= ((t/3)+1)*4;
    outbuf[temp-1] = '=';
    outbuf[temp-2] = '=';
}

//for(int i=0; i < sizeof((read_cnt)*4/3);i++)
printf("%s",outbuf);


}
while(feof(in)==0);





return 0;
}
```

When I type the example I get on wikipedia of 'Man is distinguished, not only by his reason, but by this singular passion from
other animals, which is a lust of the mind, that by a perseverance of delight
in the continued and indefatigable generation of knowledge, exceeds the short
vehemence of any carnal pleasure.', it should be 'TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBvbmx5IGJ5IGhpcyByZWFzb24sIGJ1dCBieSB0aGlz
IHNpbmd1bGFyIHBhc3Npb24gZnJvbSBvdGhlciBhbmltYWxzLCB3aGljaCBpcyBhIGx1c3Qgb2Yg
dGhlIG1pbmQsIHRoYXQgYnkgYSBwZXJzZXZlcmFuY2Ugb2YgZGVsaWdodCBpbiB0aGUgY29udGlu
dWVkIGFuZCBpbmRlZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXRpb24gb2Yga25vd2xlZGdlLCBleGNlZWRzIHRo
ZSBzaG9ydCB2ZWhlbWVuY2Ugb2YgYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3VyZS4='

but I get

'TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBvbmx5IGJ5IGhpcyByZWFzb24sIGJ1dCBieSB0aGlz
IHNpbmd1bGFyIHBhc3Npb24gZnJvbQpvdGhlciBhbmltYWxzLCB3aGljaCBpcyBhIGx1c3Qgb2Yg
dGhlIG1pbmQsIHRoYXQgYnkgYSBwZXJzZXZlcmFuY2Ugb2YgZGVsaWdodAppbiB0aGUgY29udGlu
dWVkIGFuZCBpbmRlZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXRpb24gb2Yga25vd2xlZGdlLCBleGNlZWRzIHRo
ZSBzaG9ydAp2ZWhlbWVuY2Ugb2YgYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3VyZS4KZGdlLCBleGNlZWRzIHRo'

which is the same thing but with this little extra on the end 'KZGdlLCBleGNlZWRzIHRo'. Can someone please help me understand where this extra code is coming from ? thanks so much

Comment: Sounds like you've eaten the null-terminator. I'd advise you to compile the program with something like address-sanitizer or valgrind.

Comment: Note that `ZGdlLCBleGNlZWRzIHRo` also occurs in the correct solution, which also indicates that you simply forget to add a `\0` in the last loop round. Actually the only place where you set `\0` is in the intermediate loop but only if another value of `outbuf` is already `\0` which I do not see why it should ever be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
for (int i = 0; i < read_cnt - 2; i=i+3)
```

... instead of...

```
for (int i = 0; i < read_cnt; i=i+3)
```

I tried to understand what exactly you are trying to do by checking the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), but I cannot say that I have understood the whole thing correctly.

Comment: Just figured it out, I needed to fill outbuf with 0s. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of problems in you code.

1. You are reading past your data buffer.

   ```
   i3 = inbuf[i+2];
   i2 = inbuf[i+1] << 8;
   ```

   You really should add checks, for not getting values outside [0..read_cnt-1]
2. You are using shift on signed integers. That would give you interesting results when working with non-ASCII text or binary data

   ```
   i3 = (unsigned char*)inbuf[i+2];
   i2 = (unsigned char*)inbuf[i+1] << 8;
   i1 = (unsigned char*)inbuf[i] << 16;
   ```

   Reason is that `char` is a signed type, which is expanded to `int` with all high bits set when the char has bit 7 set (exceeds `0x7f`)

   Also `combine` *should* be `unsigned`.
3. You are not terminating `outbuf` after encoding loop.

   You are trying to find `0`, but it is not there...

   Instead of multiple paddings, you might try the following:

   ```
   int pos = read_cnt * 4;
   switch (read_cnt % 3)
   {
   case 1: outbuf[pos++] = '=';
   case 2: outbuf[pos++] = '=';
   case 0: outbuf[pos++] = '\r';
           outbuf[pos++] = '\n';
           outbuf[pos] = 0;
   }
   ```
4. `read_cnt` *should be* `ssize_t`